# How to TryPeek on a BlockingCollection based on a ConcurrentStack

Tags: .net, blockingcollection

I have a `BlockingCollection` based on a `ConcurrentStack`:

`Dim stackBase As New ConcurrentStack(Of MyObject)
Dim myStack = New BlockingCollection(Of MyObject)(stackBase)`

In one of my producers I want to check the top item in the blocking collection before adding a new item. I understand the item might be removed by a consumer in the meantime. In this case that isn't a problem because I am just trying to avoid burying certain objects.

The `ConcurrentStack` has `TryPeek` which would work perfectly, but I don't have access to the `stackBase` object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should expose the behavior you are looking for by exposing a service that accesses your concurrent stack and blocking collection.  That way you can mock the behavior at test time as well.

```
interface IWhateverYourCollectionService {
   //TryPeak();
   //Any other methods that make sense for what your doing.
}
```

In this way you could store both of the objects in the service or have them grabbed from a factory and expose the appropriate behavior through your service.

Comment: So how would I implement TryPeek against my BlockingCollection?

Comment: added clairification, should probably be done in the constructor of what implements the service interface

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting that I figure out a way to get access to the ConcurrentStack object so I can use TryPeek against it directly. That could work, but I was hoping there was some way I could just use the BlockingCollection.

Comment: Well you would not need to "get access" the code you provided has the initialization of both objects.  It could easily be in the constructor of a concrete implementation of a service.  Then store off the two collections into a private property.  Then through methods implemented on the service you can provide the functionality without accessing the collections in unsafe ways.